# Objectmapper Dictionary To Json swift? Swift 2 -> Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift3, objectmapper

I have a problem to get my `Dictionary` json to my "MyOwnClass". In Swift 2 everything was fine.

My Json Structure:

```
[
    {
        "dataString1" : "value",
        "dataInt1" : 3277
    },
    {
        "dataString1" : "value",
        ... and so on
```

I used the `Objectmapper` in Swift 2.x, but now I want to convert everything in Swift 3.

My old code:

```
do {
    let jsonSerilization = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(json, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as! NSArray

    for jsonCount in 0..<jsonSerilization.count {
         let singleData = Mapper<MyOwnClass>().map(jsonSerilization[jsonCount])
         print(singleData.dataString1) //gotValue
    }


} catch {
    ...
    }
```

Now the line `jsonSerilization[jsonCount]` is a dictionary. In the console I find all my values.

But I want this dictionary inside my "MyOwnClass" structure. I can not make to cast my dictionary to a string. I tried dictionary.description but this string has a wrong format.

MyOwnClass Strucutre isn't special.

```
class MyOwnClass : Mappable {
 var dataString1: String?
 var dataInt1: Int?

 required init?(map: Map){
     mapping(map: map)
 }

 func mapping(map: Map) {
    dataString1 <- map["dataString1"]
    dataInt1 <- map["dataInt1"]
 }
}
```

How can I transport the values from the dictionary inside my "MyOwnClass"?
Sure I could do it manually, but I want an automatic solution.

I googled a lot convert dictionary to json string, but nothing helped. Thank you

**EDIT**
It seems that ObjectMapper can't parse this structure of json (State: 10/2016)
Please let me know, if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 3):

First of all – as always –  **use Swift native collection types**. You are going to throw away the important type information.

Second of all, stop using ugly C-style `for` loops.

Third of all, you don't need mutable containers at all when only reading the JSON.

```
let jsonSerialization = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with:json, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]

for item in jsonSerialization {
    let singleData = Mapper<MyOwnClass>().map(JSON:item)
    print(singleData.dataString1) //gotValue
}
```

**Edit:**

You don't need `ObjectMapper` at all for two properties. It's even less code without the library

```
class MyOwnClass  {
  var dataString1: String?
  var dataInt1: Int?

  init(JSON: [String:Any]) {
    self.dataString1  = JSON["dataString1"] as? String
    self.dataInt1  = JSON["dataInt1"] as? Int
  }
}
```

and call it

```
let singleData = MyOwnClass(JSON:item)
```

Comment: Yeah I had this code, too. But my problem is that item is now a dictionary with values  "dataString1" : "value" and  "dataInt" : 3277. But how should I transport these data inside my "MyOwnClass". This is my problem. I'm sorry, I don't described it perfectly.

Comment: Then change your mapper to the appropriate keys for example `dataString <- map["dataString1"]` but consider that the property remains `dataString` (of course you can change that, too).

Comment: I'm sorry. This was a bug. But this line let singleData = Mapper<MyOwnClass>().map(item) throws an error. In Swift 3 I have to set a prefix:
let singleData = Mapper<MyOwnClass>().map(JSONString: item)
But this one doesn't work, because item isn't a string. How do I get this one to a json string?

Comment: I update the answer. According to the documentation the parameter label seems to be `JSON`. But basically `Objectmapper` for two key/values is overkill. You can do that without the library changing two lines.

Comment: Okay, thank you for ur 2nd opinion. Then it isn't my stupidness. Good to know. Then I have to fix that manually.

Answer (score 1):

Use `[[String:Any]]` instead of `NSArray` also `JSONObjectWithData` is write like below in Swift 3.

```
let jsonSerilization = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: json, options: []) as! [[String:Any]]
for dic in jsonSerilization {
     let singleData = Mapper<MyOwnClass>().map(dic)
     print(singleData.dataString1) //gotValue
}
```